# Jacoco report in command line

Tags: java, jacoco

I have to write a .sh launching an UI application covered with Jacoco. On exit, a jacoco report must be generated.

I'm not able to generate the jacoco.exec with this simple command :

```
java -jar ../binaries/editor.debug/application.jar -javaagent:/atgl/products/jacoco/0.6.3/lib/jacocoagent.jar=destfile=jacoco.exec
```

The first part of the command works fine and launch the program, but the -javaagent option doesn't generate report and the program doesn't launch.
If I do a syntax error it's exactly the same behavior.

What's wrong with my command ?

Secondly, this command create a .exec file. How can I generate a .html report in command line ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem was the position of the -javaagent option. It needed to be in first position, like this :

```
java -javaagent:/atgl/products/jacoco/0.6.3/lib/jacocoagent.jar=destfile=jacoco.exec -jar ../binaries/editor.debug/application.jar
```

Then as Godin said, it's not possible to generate report in command line. I created an ant file **exectoreport.xml** with a rule **do_jacoco_reports**. The rule is launched by a script exectoreport.sh, that must be called after the natural exit of the application.

Answer (score 4):

By using jacococli.jar from jacoco 0.7.9 version, now reports can be generated using command line. I was trying the same and able to generate the report using commandline. If you are able to generate jacoco.exec file successfully use below command to generate the report.

```
java -jar "your local path/jacococli.jar" report "your local path/jacoco.exec" --classfiles "project path to class files" --html "local path\jacoco-report" --name myReport --sourcefiles "project path\src\main\java"
```

You should be able to see report in html format. Reference http://www.jacoco.org/jacoco/trunk/doc/cli.html

Comment: How did you get jacococli.jar file? I added as dependencies in pom.xml but it did not generate anything for me.

Comment: I downloaded the jar and got that added in my enterprise nexus repo.

Comment: To where should the `--classfiles` option direct to?

Answer (score 3):

Usage of JaCoCo involves two steps - gathering of coverage information and generation of report. So nothing wrong with your command - it gathers coverage information into `.exec` file. After this you can generate report using [Ant](http://www.eclemma.org/jacoco/trunk/doc/ant.html) or [Maven](http://www.eclemma.org/jacoco/trunk/doc/maven.html), or built your own report generator using [JaCoCo APIs](http://www.eclemma.org/jacoco/trunk/doc/api/index.html) - JaCoCo does not yet provide a out-of-the-box command line interface for report generation, however there is an [example of API usage for report generation](http://www.eclemma.org/jacoco/trunk/doc/examples/java/ReportGenerator.java).

**Update (2/8/2019)**

[JaCoCo provides command line interface](https://www.jacoco.org/jacoco/trunk/doc/cli.html) since version 0.8.0.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But I can't even generate a .exec file ! Need I to compile my application in a special way to instrument it before executing it with jacoco agent ? I think I will use ant to generate the report once I have the .exec file

Comment: Precision :  the .exec file si generated when I enter -javaagent:/atgl/products/jacoco/0.6.3/lib/jacocoagent.jar=destfile=jacoco.exec in the VM argument field in eclipse. It doesn't work on command line

Answer (score 0):

if you have added jacoco plugins into your pom.xml then simply run this command and you will see jacoco report inside target\site\jacoco

```
mvn jacoco:report
```

**To add jacoco plugin into your pom.xml, paste below code snippet:**

```
<plugins>
    <plugin>
        <groupId>org.jacoco</groupId>
        <artifactId>jacoco-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>0.8.2</version>
        <executions>
            <execution>
                <goals>
                    <goal>prepare-agent</goal>
                </goals>
            </execution>
        </executions>
    </plugin>
```