# java coverage is 0% with Junit & Jacoco from the command line

Tags: java, junit, code-coverage, jacoco

I used only 'command line' in all of these processes and I want to do that.(not using Ant, maven, gradle, etc.)

I would like to run Junit test case and JaCoCo coverage estimation.

First, below is my code

`Calculator.java`:

```
public class Calculator {
  public int evaluate(String expression) {

    int sum = 0;
    for(String summand: expression.split("\\+"))
        sum += Integer.valueOf(summand);
    System.out.println("Hello World!!");
    return sum;
  }
}
```

`CalculatorTest.java`:

```
import static org.junit.Assert.assertEquals;
import org.junit.Test;

public class CalculatorTest {
  @Test
  public void evaluatesExpression(){
    Calculator calculator = new Calculator();
    int sum = calculator.evaluate("1+2+3");
    assertEquals(6, sum);
  }
}
```

2 java files are in `C\Cal` and `Cal` folder contains 4 jar files
(`junit-4.12.jar`, `hamcrest-core-1.3.jar`, `jacococli.jar`, `jacocoagent.jar`)

In this situation, I maked classfile `Calculator.class`.

```
javac Calculator.java
```

And then, I maked `exec` (I think it is execution file of jacoco) file to estimate unit-test coverage of `Calculator.java` file.

```
java -javaagent:jacocoagent.jar=destfile=jacoco.exec
```

After that, I extracted the report using the `exec` file and command

```
java -jar jacococli.jar report jacoco.exec --classfiles Calculator.class --html "report" --name jacocoReport --sourcefiles "Calulator.java"
```

However, the test coverage in the html report I made was 0%.

Here is my questions:

1. Do you know why my coverage is 0%?
2. Is there any problem in trying to extract the coverage result I want?
3. When calculating the coverage of the `Calculator.java` file by `CalculatorTest.java` code and extracting the report, is it correct to write `--classfiles` only using `Calculator.class`?
4. There is no difference in the results even if you insert both `Calculator.java` and `CalculatorTest.java` in `--sourcefiles`. Did I put it wrong? Or what is the effect of `--sourcefiles`?

And this is the Internet pages I referenced:

- https://github.com/junit-team/junit4/wiki/Getting-started
- [Jacoco report in command line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40810496/jacoco-report-in-command-line)

Comment: Offline Instrumentation is your keyword. Google it.

Comment: What are you using to build your project (As in Gradle/ Maven)?

Comment: I just using 'cmd' on window(like terminal on linux).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Do you know why my coverage is 0%?
>
> There is no difference in the results even if you insert both `Calculator.java` and `CalculatorTest.java` in `--sourcefiles`. Did I put it wrong? Or what is the effect of `--sourcefiles`?

`--sourcefiles` should point on a directory containing packages. And in your case your files use default package (no package), so `--sourcefiles` should point on directory containing `Calculator.java`.

> Is there any problem in trying to extract the coverage result I want?

No - there is not problem. For example having `Calculator.java` in directory `src` and `CalculatorTest.java` in directory `test-src`

```
mkdir classes
javac src/Calculator.java -d classes
mkdir test-classes
javac -cp junit-4.12.jar:classes test-src/CalculatorTest.java -d test-classes
java -javaagent:jacoco-0.8.1/lib/jacocoagent.jar -cp junit-4.12.jar:hamcrest-core-1.3.jar:classes:test-classes org.junit.runner.JUnitCore CalculatorTest
java -jar jacoco-0.8.1/lib/jacococli.jar report jacoco.exec --classfiles classes --sourcefiles src --html report
```

produce following report

[image: report]

> When calculating the coverage of the `Calculator.java` file by `CalculatorTest.java` code and extracting the report, is it correct to write `--classfiles` only using `Calculator.class`?

`--classfiles` should point on class files, or directories containing class files, or archives containing class files, which should appear in report. `CalculatorTest.class` was not specified in example above, so it doesn't appear in report. And if specified:

```
java -jar jacoco-0.8.1/lib/jacococli.jar report jacoco.exec --classfiles classes --sourcefiles src --classfiles test-classes --sourcefiles test-src --html report
```

[image: report]

Comment: I really appreciate your kind reply.
However, when I use the 'java -javaagent:jacoco-0.8.1/lib/jacocoagent.jar -cp junit-4.12.jar:hamcrest-core-1.3.jar:classes:test-classes org.junit.runner.JUnitCore CalculatorTest' command, the error indication is "can not find (or load) class 'org.junit.runner.junitcore'

Comment: @jeongookjang on Windows class path entries delimited by semicolon `;` , i.e. `java -javaagent:jacoco-0.8.1/lib/jacocoagent.jar -cp junit-4.12.jar;hamcrest-core-1.3.jar;classes;test-classes org.junit.runner.JUnitCore CalculatorTest`

Comment: I solved the problem thanks to you.
One more question. How do I view the coverage percentage of a line, not the percentage of an instruction's coverage?

Comment: @jeongookjang the format of a report is not configurable. If you absolutely need percentage of lines instead of instructions, then divide missed on total. Values can be extracted programmatically from XML and CSV reports. And please don't forget to mark answer as accepted.